# how to automatically change ip address c#

Tags: c#, ip

I have an application that open Url evrey 10 secondsusing Process. I want to change my ip address each browser opening. How can i change my ip automatically evrey 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can change a static IP in your LAN with netsh. But i don't think that is what you want. You can of course not programatically change your IP assigned by you provider.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? The optimist in me hopes you're trying to load test an application , but it sounds like you're trying to spoof something. In short - you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load a proxy list for your program to use (NEVER HARD-CODE PROXIES). Tell your program to select one out a text file. Your going to want to make sure to catch any exceptions in case you load a bad proxy, that way you can tell it to use the next one. I will tell you free proxies are bad for security, and reliability. *Hint **HttpWebRequest.Proxy**
Good luck!